# Running Total for Current & Previous Year on weekly basis

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.6

This query provides Year to date numbers for both Price and Square Feet of the current year and the previous year to date. This is more like the Running Total of the current Year and the Previous year with respect to the weeks in this case from 1 through 7 and so on..... (week 7th of 2017 ended on 02/19/2017) of the current year and the previous year(week 7th of 2016 ended on 02/22/2016). The reason why I am using subqueries is because this is the ***only*** way I know to get around this situation. And of course if you think there is a shorter, viable alternative of executing this query, please advice.

`Actual_Sale_Date` holds data on all of the seven days of the week but we cut off on Sunday that is why 2/22/2016 (Sunday ending 7th week of 2016) and 2/19/2017 (Sunday ending 7th week of 2017).

I tried `"Actual_Sale_Date" = date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1` this function only returns the previous week data ending on the passed Sunday. I took a look at `interval` since `dateadd` does not exist in postgresql but could not get my ways around with it.

My query:

```
select (money(Sum("Price") / COUNT("Price"))) as "Avg_Value YTD",
Round(Avg("Price"/"Sq_Ft"),+2) as "Avg_PPSF YTD",

(select 
(money(Sum("Price") / COUNT("Price")))  from allsalesdata
where "Actual_Sale_Date" >=  '01/01/2016' AND "Actual_Sale_Date" < '02/22/2016'
and "Work_ID" = 'SO') AS "Last Year at this time Avg_Value", 


(select Round(Avg("Price"/"Sq_Ft"),+2)
from allsalesdata
where "Actual_Sale_Date" >=  '01/01/2016' AND "Actual_Sale_Date" <  '02/22/2016' 
and "Work_ID" = 'SO') AS "Last Year at this time Avg_PPSF"


from allsalesdata
where "Actual_Sale_Date" >=  '01/01/2017' AND "Actual_Sale_Date" <'02/20/2017'
and "Work_ID" = 'SO'
```

Sample Data:

```
Price       Sq_Ft        Actual_Sale_Date        Work_ID

45871       3583           01/15/2016             SO
55874       4457           02/05/2016             SO
88745       4788           02/20/2016             SO
58745       1459           01/10/2016             SO
88749       2145           01/25/2017             SO
74856       1478           01/25/2017             SO
74586       4587           01/31/2017             ABC
74745       1142           02/10/2017             SO
74589       2214           02/19/2017             SO
```

Comment: do you need to generate a date series by weeks?

Comment: The query has a `weeks` series requirements. Running total of the columns as the year progresses.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not clear to me, a cumulative total by week?

Comment: For example, Total 1st week 2016  Total 1st week 2017?

Comment: Yes you can say that. E.g. `"Actual_Sale_Date" = date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1` this function only returns the previous week data ending on the passed Sunday. I took a look at `interval` since `dateadd` does not exist in postgresql but could not get my ways around with it. `For example, Total 1st week 2016 Total 1st week 2017?` Yes exactly but running total as we enter March, April, etc...

Comment: I'm sure there is an interesting question here but the requirements are totally confusing. Add sample data and wanted results.

Comment: Also add: when do weeks start? On Mondays? On Sundays? On the same day as the 1st day of a year?

Comment: And please add the tag specifying the version of PostgreSQL you are using.

Comment: I am using pgAdmin III @ Andriy. I have attached sample data and clarified my requirements @ ypercube.

Comment: Sample data **and** sample output please. PgAdmin3 is a GUI tool. Run `select version();` to find the version.

Comment: 22-Feb-2016 was a Monday. 19-Feb-2017 was Sunday. Are your weeks Sun-Sat or Mon-Sun? And when does the first week of the year start?

Comment: And do you want one result for each year (from Jan-01 till Feb-whatever) or 1 for each week?

Comment: since 02/22/2016 is the 8th week and will only calculate upto end of 7th week which is 02/21/2016 maybe change the query to this:
where "Actual_Sale_Date" >=  '01/01/2016' AND EXTRACT(WEEK FROM Actual_Sale_Date) <  {the week of the cut off date}?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 9.6beta3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit. My bad @ ypercube you are right, it should be 02/21/2016. Week goes from Monday through Sunday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you need (assuming you have a recent version of PG):

```
SELECT DISTINCT wk AS "Week",
       sum("Price")::money FILTER (WHERE yr = 2017) OVER w / 
       count("Price") FILTER (WHERE yr = 2017) OVER w AS "Avg_Value YTD",
       sum("Price")::money FILTER (WHERE yr = 2017) OVER w / 
       sum("Sq_Ft") FILTER (WHERE yr = 2017) OVER w AS "Avg_PPSF YTD",
       sum("Price")::money FILTER (WHERE yr = 2016) OVER w / 
       count("Price") FILTER (WHERE yr = 2016) OVER w AS "Last Year this time Avg_Value",
       sum("Price")::money FILTER (WHERE yr = 2016) OVER w / 
       sum("Sq_Ft") FILTER (WHERE yr = 2016) OVER w AS "Last Year this time Avg_PPSF",
FROM (
    SELECT extract(isoyear from "Actual_Sale_Date")::integer AS yr,
           extract(week from "Actual_Sale_Date")::integer AS wk,
           "Price", "Sq_Ft"
    FROM allsalesdata
    WHERE "Work_ID" = 'SO') sub
-- optional, show only completed weeks in this year:
WHERE wk <= extract(week from CURRENT_DATE)::integer - 1 
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY wk)
ORDER BY wk;
```

In the inner query the year and week of the sale date are extracted for every sale. The week starts on Monday, as per your requirement.

In the main query these rows are processed as a single partition *frame*, i.e. from the start of the partition (= first row) to the *last peer* of the current row. Since the window definition orders the rows by `wk`, all rows from the start (week = 1) to the current week are included in the summarization. This will give you the running total. The `sum()` and `count()` functions filter by the year in question and the `DISTINCT` clause ensures that you get only a single row per week.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 9.6beta3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, it works great but do you know why it shows data for the Eighth week even though we are still in the Eighth week of 2017. Should it not wait until Sunday of this week or Monday of next week?

Comment: @JakeWagner: This query shows data for the weeks from the beginning of the year up to the current one (inclusive). This week is week 8.

Comment: If you want only full weeks, you can modify the WHERE clause and subtract 1: `WHERE wk <= extract(week from CURRENT_DATE)::integer - 1`.